# Pygame The collision for my game works, but only for the last placed image

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, random, time

class Game(object):
def main(self, screen):
    bg = pygame.image.load('data/bg.png')
    house1 = pygame.image.load('data/house1.png')

    playerIdle = pygame.image.load('data/playerIdle.png')
    playerRight = pygame.image.load('data/playerRight.png')
    playerLeft = pygame.image.load('data/playerLeft.png')
    playerUp = pygame.image.load('data/playerUp.png')
    playerX = 0
    playerY = 50

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    spriteList = []
    gameIsRunning = False

    house1Selected = False
    houseInWorld = False


    while 1:
        clock.tick(30)

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return
    #delete all sprites on the game(only able to do this in god mode)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d and gameIsRunning == False:
        spriteList = []
    #press 6 to select the house1 image to be placed
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_6 and gameIsRunning == False:
        house1Selected = True
    #spawning the image"house1" at the position of the mouse by pressing space
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and gameIsRunning == False and house1Selected == True:
        spriteList.append((house1, mouse))
        house1XY = mouse
        houseInWorld = True

    #run mode where you cannot build and you move(where I want collision)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_r:
        gameIsRunning = True
    #god mode where you can build and place the house1 image
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_g:
        gameIsRunning = False

    #this is run mode where you can move around and where I want collision
    if(gameIsRunning == True):
        #player Movements
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            if playerY <= 0:
                playerY = 0
            if playerY >= 0:
                screen.blit(playerUp, (playerX, playerY))
                playerY = playerY - 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            PLAYERDOWNLIMIT = 700 - playerIdle.get_height()
            if(playerY >= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                playerY = PLAYERDOWNLIMIT
            if(playerY <= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                screen.blit(playerIdle, (playerX, playerY))
                playerY = playerY + 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            if playerX <= 0:
                playerX = 0
            if playerX >= 0:
                screen.blit(playerLeft, (playerX, playerY))
                playerX = playerX - 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT = 1200 - playerIdle.get_width()
            if(playerX >= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                playerX = PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT
            if(playerX <= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                screen.blit(playerRight, (playerX, playerY))
                playerX = playerX + 2

        #collision

        if(house1InWorld == True):
            house1Rect = pygame.Rect(house1XY[0], house1XY[1], 64, 64)

            if playerRect.colliderect(house1Rect) and playerX <= house1XY[0]:
                playerX = playerX - 2
            if playerRect.colliderect(house1Rect) and playerX >= house1XY[0]:
                playerX = playerX + 2
            if playerRect.colliderect(house1Rect) and playerY <= house1XY[1]:
                playerY = playerY - 2
            if playerRect.colliderect(house1Rect) and playerY >= house1XY[1]:
                playerY = playerY + 2

    #this is godmode where you can move around fast n preview where you place images but I don't want collision here
    if(gameIsRunning == False):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            if playerY <= 0:
                playerY = 0
            if playerY >= 0:
                screen.blit(playerUp, (playerX, playerY))
                playerY = playerY - 8
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            PLAYERDOWNLIMIT = 700 - playerIdle.get_height()
            if(playerY >= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                playerY = PLAYERDOWNLIMIT
            if(playerY <= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                screen.blit(playerIdle, (playerX, playerY))
                playerY = playerY + 8
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            if playerX <= 0:
                playerX = 0
            if playerX >= 0:
                screen.blit(playerLeft, (playerX, playerY))
                playerX = playerX - 8
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT = 1200 - playerIdle.get_width()
            if(playerX >= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                playerX = PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT
            if(playerX <= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                screen.blit(playerRight, (playerX, playerY))
                playerX = playerX + 8

    screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    #what block are you placing(displays preview)
    if(gameIsRunning == False and house1Selected == True):
        screen.blit(house1, (mouse))

    if(gameIsRunning == True):
        playerXSTR = str(playerX)
        playerYSTR = str(playerY)
        playerXYSTR = ("(" + playerXSTR + ", " + playerYSTR + ")")
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
        playercord = font.render(playerXYSTR, 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(playercord, (0, 0))
        runMode = font.render("Run Mode(Cannot build)", 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(runMode, (0, 20))
    if(gameIsRunning == False):
        playerXSTR = str(playerX)
        playerYSTR = str(playerY)
        playerXYSTR = ("(" + playerXSTR + ", " + playerYSTR + ")")
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
        playercord = font.render(playerXYSTR, 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(playercord, (0, 0))
        godMode = font.render("God Mode(Can build)", 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(godMode, (0, 20))

    for (img, pos) in spriteList:
        screen.blit(img, pos)
    screen.blit(playerIdle, (playerX, playerY))

    pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sandbox')
Game().main(screen)
```

In my game, you start in "god mode", where you can place objects. When you finish placing objects and go into "run mode", however, the game is in realtime and there's collision and other physical effects.

So the collision I have in my game right now works only part of the time.

When you press space, you spawn the 'house1' image at the location of the mouse and it sets the house1's XY coordinates, and sets `house1InWorld = True` (which affects collision).

Collision is goes into effect when the house1 image is spawned, because of the house1inWorld attribute. So if you press r (to go into run mode), the collision works for one house1 instance. But when you spawn 2 instances of house1 (at different locations), the collision only works for the recently placed house1.

How should I change my code so that collision works no matter how many house1's you spawn?

Comment: is your indentation wrong? You only have the event loop inside the While True loop.

Answer (score 1):

You only store the position of the last placed house and check the collision against that.

You should create a list of house positions, and loop though them to check for collision.
Something like this:

```
houses1XY = []
houses1XY.append(mouse)
#and later
for house1XY in houses1XY:
    house1Rect = pygame.Rect(house1XY[0], house1XY[1], 64, 64)
```

Since you moved the houses to a list, you no longer need the `houseInWorld`. You already have the information about in the list. You can check if the list is not empty -> so there is a house placed already by evaluating the list. It returns true if it is not empty.

```
if houses1XY:
   #enable realtime etc.
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response to your answer. But how would I then check for collision using all the positions in the list? because I've added your code in and the positions are added to the list but It still only counts collision for the most recently placed house position.

Comment: are you sure? the third line in the code I provided is a loop for each house.

Comment: yes so just a few things should I put the houses1XY = [] inside or outside of the while loop because currently it is out which I think is where it belongs so it doesn't remove each position each time you add a new one. The houses1XY.append(mouse) is under the if statement for if you press space and then I have the for house1XY in houses1XY: outside of the if statement(for pressing space to spawn the house) And the if houses1XY: is where the collision was.

Comment: the collision check is the `for house1XY in houses1XY` put this where the collision was

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it's the collision check? so I should put it under if housesXY: where I have my collision?

Comment: You can ignore the last snipped. You want to loop through the list of coordinates and check the collision for each house.